# tikz trees: How to not draw a single edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I want to draw a tree and not draw specific edges. I try it like this

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
      \node (r) {$r$}
      child { node (T1) {$T_1$} }
      child { edge from parent[draw=none] node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
      child { node (Tn) {$T_n$} };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This does drop the edge of the middle child, but for some reason shifts the node upwards. I want it to be placed at the same level as its siblings. 
Is this doable without manually drawing a node between `(T1)` and `(Tn)`?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:**
After clarifying, what is the problem, I suggest to try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
      \node (r) {$r$}
      child { node (T1) {$T_1$} }
      child {node {$\ldots$}  edge from parent[draw=none]}
      child { node (Tn) {$T_n$} };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit (2):** Thank to @cfr, which pointed me to simple solution: your line

```
child { edge from parent[draw=none] node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
```

reorder to

```
 child {node[draw=none] {$\ldots$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
```

and you will  get desired results. Deep explanation you can find in cfr answer. It is very instructive.

Comment: Well, the child simply disappears. I want the `\ldots` to be in the child's position without having to manually place a node between the two siblings.

Comment: I was guessing this ... however about this your question isn't clear. As you can see, meanwhile I already add this option to my answer.

Comment: I could do it like this, but I'm interested in whether I can actually have the `child` be placed correctly, but without an edge from parent. So I would like to avoid having to manually `\draw` a node or line. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @oarfish, ok, now I see, what you like to achieve. This is simple and your solution is on the right way ... See edit of my answer.

Comment: Ah yes, this works. It feels like cheating though. I would have to adjust it for a different background colour.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise before because I never draw trees this way (hardly ever). But this is not a good solution. The problem with @oarfish 's code is that it doesn't obey TikZ's syntax for drawing edges. `edge from parent` is just an `edge` with a special style. You need to specify it with the same syntax as any other edge. See my answer for details of various ways to do this. No special tricks are necessary - just standard `\path ... edge ... node ...` stuff. `edge from parent` is an `edge` operation *and* a `style`.

Answer (score 8):

I present two solutions. The first uses the standard TikZ tree syntax. The second uses the powerful tree-drawing package, **forest**.

---

## TikZ

The problem has nothing to do with the fact that you are not drawing the edge. The problem is that you cannot modify the `edge from parent` style in that way. `edge from parent` is *both* and `edge` drawing operation *and* a style. The code in the question confuses the two, but this is easier to explain with examples.

To see this, just change the line

```
  child { edge from parent[draw=none] node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
```

to

```
  child { edge from parent[draw=green] node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
```

[image: green edge]

Clearly, this is not the right way to go about this. `edge from parent` is an `edge` drawing operation and a `style` and we want to change the *style*. But we cannot change a TikZ style (typically, anyhow) by saying `<style name>[<new options>]`. This isn't the right syntax. Instead, we'd normally say something like

```
<style name>/.style={<new options>}
```

or

```
<style name>/.append style={<new options>}
```

or, in some cases,

```
<style name>={<new options>}
```

but we can only use these things inside `\tikzset{}` or somewhere else that TikZ expects a style to be given.

In the case of a child path, TikZ expects to find `edge from parent` operation at the end. If we put a node ***after*** it, TikZ assumes we want to create a ***label*** on the path and, by default, this is placed midway. If the node is supposed to be the node in the tree, it needs to come ***after*** the `edge`, just as in other cases of drawing edges in TikZ.

So,

```
  child { node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} edge from parent[draw=green] }
```

produces

[image: node in tree]

and

```
  child { node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} edge from parent[draw=green] node [draw=none, font=\scriptsize] {label} node [font=\scriptsize, at end, draw=none] {end label} }
```

produces

[image: labelled edge]

And, of course,

```
  child { node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} edge from parent[draw=none] }
```

produces

[image: properly placed node in tree]

If we prefer to specify this wherever, we can do so, but we need to make sure that the `edge from parent` operation still comes at the end. This is the default, so not using it does the trick. We can still change its style, provided we just change its style. For example,

```
  child { [edge from parent/.style={draw=none}] node[draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
```

will produce the same output.

For convenience, and to please Zarko, we can create a **forest**-alike style which does this more easily:

```
   no edge/.style={
     edge from parent/.append style={draw=none}
   }
```

and then say

```
  child { [no edge] node [draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
```

to produce the required result.

Making the example complete,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [
   every node/.style={circle, draw},
   no edge/.style={
     edge from parent/.append style={draw=none}
   }
 ]
  \node (r) {$r$}
  child { node (T1) {$T_1$} }
  child { [no edge] node [draw=none] (ellipsis) {$\ldots$} }
  child { node (Tn) {$T_n$} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: standard no edge]

---

## Forest

If you are willing to use a different package, **forest** has a `no edge` option which does what it says on the tin for whichever node(s) you apply it to.

For example:

```
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  forest circles/.style={
    for tree={
      math content,
      draw,
      circle,
      minimum size=20pt,
      inner sep=0pt,
      text centered
    },
    no edge/.append style={draw=none}
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  forest circles,
  [r
    [T_1]
    [\cdots, no edge]
    [T_n]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: missing edge]

Comment: `forest` seems to be very  powerful package. Unfortunately his syntax is to me not so intuitive as at standard TikZ tree (or I need more time to learn it ..), so I wish, if some option from `forest` (like this, which you use in your answer) ones will be available in TikZ tree too.

Comment: @Zarko It seems unlikely that the basic TikZ trees stuff is going to enable the sort of functionality provided by **forest** any time soon, just because the latter is so specialised. I know what you mean about the syntax, but it becomes very easy after a little experimentation. I now find **qtree**'s syntax indigestible, though I drew an entire series of trees with it at one point, and wrote macros to make it compatible with Beamer overlays. I think **forest** is easier because every node gets brackets and not just some. So the structure is easier to read off the syntax.

Comment: @Zarko Actually, in this case, it is easy. Here's a `no edge` style for TikZ trees.

Comment: wel `no edge` doesn't work in TikZ trees, only in graph (by LuaTeX, if my quick check of manual was correct). Anway, reading manula again I found example which for similar case as is asked here. I will improved my answer (thank to you).

Comment: @Zarko I meant that my answer now provides a `no edge` style which I've defined. Look at the code in the first part of my answer: it is entirely done with TikZ trees and the full example before the **forest** version defines and uses `no edge`. (I said *here's* a `no edge` style. That is, I'm providing one in my answer as it doesn't exist by default.)

Comment: I just read it. Is there a way to give bounty to your answer? How to do this? It is really good!

Comment: @Zarko I'm glad you like it ;).

Comment: I wish I could accept more than one answer. This is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a duplicate before find this answer and I used opacity as a hack:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,draw}]
      \node (r) {$r$}
      child { node (T1) {$T_1$} }
      child[opacity=0] { node[draw=white,opacity=1]  {$\ldots$} }
      child { node (Tn) {$T_n$} };
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: Added as another option