# One-period multinomial model

Tags: tikz-trees

I am trying to draw a One-period multinomial model that looks like this: [image]

But I am having trouble using the tikzpicture package to achieve this, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! What's the problem exactly? 'I am having trouble' doesn't give us much to go on. Please post the code you've been trying and tell us what trouble you have with it. (E.g. it gives an error (exact text of error) or it produces something which is like X, but you expected something like Y.)

Comment: See how much is your question related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280285/tikz-trees-how-to-not-draw-a-single-edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answers in [tikz trees: How to not draw a single edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280285/tikz-trees-how-to-not-draw-a-single-edge):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                 grow = right,
     sibling distance = 7mm,
       level distance = 21mm,
edge from parent path = {(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)}
                        ]
\node  {$S_0$}
    child {node    {$S_0u_M$} }
    child {node    {$S_0u_{M-1}$} }
    child {node[draw=none] {$\vdots$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
    child { node    {$S_0u_2$} }
    child { node    {$S_0u_1$} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

In above example package `subdepth` is not essential, it serve only for slightly nicer indices position.