# How to remove branch for a child

Tags: tikz-pgf

I create a tree using node/child in tikz as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{nodestyle} = [circle,draw,minimum size=5pt]

\node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$A|_{\aleph_0}$}
child {node {$\vdots$}
    child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=4pt] (b1) {$S$}
        child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=0pt] {$\{X_1\}$}
            child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=1pt] {$X_1$}}}
        child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=1pt] (e) {$X_2$}}}
}
child {node {$\vdots$}
child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=2pt] (b3) {$X_1$}}}
child {node {$\cdots\cdots$}}
child {node {$\vdots$}
child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=2pt] (an) {$X_n$}}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now I want to remove the branch above \cdots in child. How do I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you will find a better solution (wait for other answers) but here is a fast hack:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\tikzstyle{nodestyle} = [circle,draw,minimum size=5pt] REPLACED WITH CODE BELOW AFTER @cfr's COMMENT
\tikzset{nodestyle/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=5pt}}
\node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$A|_{\aleph_0}$}
child {node {$\vdots$}
    child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=4pt] (b1) {$S$}
        child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=0pt] {$\{X_1\}$}
            child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=1pt] {$X_1$}}}
        child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=1pt] (e) {$X_2$}}}
}
child {node {$\vdots$}
child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=2pt] (b3) {$X_1$}}}
child[opacity=0] {node[opacity=1] {$\cdots\cdots$}}
child {node {$\vdots$}
child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=2pt] (an) {$X_n$}}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I just added zero opacity to the child and one to its node

**Edit:**

I also found a solution here: [tikz trees: How to not draw a single edge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280285/120578)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\tikzstyle{nodestyle} = [circle,draw,minimum size=5pt] REPLACED WITH CODE BELOW AFTER @cfr's COMMENT
\tikzset{nodestyle/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=5pt}}
\node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$A|_{\aleph_0}$}
child {node {$\vdots$}
    child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=4pt] (b1) {$S$}
        child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=0pt] {$\{X_1\}$}
            child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=1pt] {$X_1$}}}
        child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=1pt] (e) {$X_2$}}}
}
child {node {$\vdots$}
child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=2pt] (b3) {$X_1$}}}
child{node{$\cdots\cdots$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
child {node {$\vdots$}
child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=2pt] (an) {$X_n$}}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this makes your question a duplicate

Comment: Thanks @cfr... replaced code with equivalent using `\tikzset`