# TikZ tree hide arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a TikZ tree (using nodes and children). In some cases I do not want to draw an arrow, it is just for a few nodes so I do not want a global solution. I have set the color to `white` and `white!0` but for PDF readers that have colored backgrounds the arrow shows up.

I simply want something like

```
child[noArrow]
```

and it will not draw the arrow from the parent. I don't care the actual mechanism. I have tried opacity but that kills everything in the child.

Comment: Please add a complete minimal working example (MWE) of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280285/tikz-trees-how-to-not-draw-a-single-edge):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style={circle,draw, minimum size=1.2em}
                        ]
\node (r) {$r$}
    child {node {A}}
    child {node {B} edge from parent[draw=none]}
    child {node {C} };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or with `forest`:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={circle, draw, minimum size=2em, inner sep=2pt,
          l sep=9mm, s sep=8mm}
[r
    [A]
    [B, no edge]
    [C]
]
\end{forest}    
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before.

Comment: is it possible for `edge from parent[draw=none]` to be a part of every node style?

Comment: @MahmoudKhaled trees are not intended for such applications. It can be simply done on an other ways.